# How to deal with authentication in multi server

Tags: php, authentication

I have an application written in PHP. I currently have two instances of the application (two servers).

I would create a third server that will manage login.

Server A : Instance one
Server B : Instance two
Server C : Login

What I want :
- Step 1 : User is on Server C and he enters his credentials.
- Step 2 : Server C will redirect the user on Server A or B.
- Step 3 : Server A or B accepts the user

Is it possible to share securely the authentification between the login server and the application server ?

Comment: CURL might be a nice option

Comment: Do you use https on server C? If not, then it really does not matter if server C sends the authentication to server A/B in cleartext. If you do, then obviously public key encryption would be the best choice. Put A/B public key on server C and encrypt auth data before sending it.